# Check which <div>'s dont have a </div>

Tags: html, css

I recently was handed an old template to make changes to. Its a really long horribly indented one. In the process of adding new design, I seem to have deleted `</div>` tags in several places, and the whole thing now seems to have taken an entirely new shape. Is it possible to easily identify which `<div>`'s don't have a `</div>`. Dreamweaver was good at this, but we don't use it anymore.

Can you please suggest tools, browser add-ons or anything else that can help do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307178/any-tools-to-find-missing-html-tags

Comment: But the only `div` elements without a closing tag will be the outer-most `div`s, since they'll be closed in the order of the closing tags. Hang on, you don't version your code? Can't you simply start again (and properly indent the code before saving it as a new version)?

Comment: Incidentally, for general purpose [HTML, CSS, C style and JSON indenting: http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier](http://tools.arantius.com/tabifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program you are looking for is [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)

From the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/):

> When editing HTML it's easy to make mistakes. Wouldn't it be nice if
>   there was a simple way to fix these mistakes automatically and tidy up
>   sloppy editing into nicely layed out markup? Well now there is! Dave
>   Raggett's HTML TIDY is a free utility for doing just that. It also
>   works great on the atrociously hard to read markup generated by
>   specialized HTML editors and conversion tools, and can help you
>   identify where you need to pay further attention on making your pages
>   more accessible to people with disabilities.